# Tensorboard just show the graph a second and the graph disappear

Tags: python, tensorboard

Generally, my problem is the graph doesn't show in tensorboard. My device is ubuntu16.04, tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0, and tensorboard 1.12.0.

However, it not totally doesn't show the graph, it shows up a flash and disappears.

[The picture when it just started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVwqz.png)

[After a second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHvum.png)

My code is [here](https://github.com/zhangfuyang/stuff/blob/master/ddpg.py)(just need to check constructed function from Class DDPGLearning) and the frame of the network is [here](https://github.com/zhangfuyang/stuff/blob/master/Network.py). I hope someone could help me.

Comment: I'm also getting this. No obvious fix :/.

Comment: I also met such problem, TF board-1.12.2

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the reason was due to `sess.graph` having so many sub-graphs that Tensorboard had to zoom out to such a degree that the entire viz had disappeared from the screen.

My current solution (at the lack of a more systematic solution) is to double-click whatever node that you can click on during that brief period when the graph does show up. That way, you have a handle of that particular node, which, upon that double-click, will be expanded to fill your screen. From this point on, you can navigate through your graphs as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The graph is so deep, that it zooms out too much. It's still there, but hard to find.

I found 2 directions to resolve it:

1. You can zoom in (mouse scroll up) and go to the upper left corner of a  [graph map](http://prntscr.com/gf-VbvOB8gd9)
2. You can find the element g#root and delete the "transform" property. Unfortunately, the graph will disappear after moving or zooming it.